# ¿Cómo mantener las dimensiones de un div según el título que obtenga?

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive

Tengo una gran duda que llevo tiempo sin resolver y es cómo poder mantener las dimensiones de un grupo de varios `div`, es decir si la primera columna tiene como título `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit` y el segundo que viene a continuación tiene como título `Integer ut leo purus. Fusce leo augue, consectetur a massa id, mollis accumsan diam.`. La diferencia de estos títulos es la longitud de caracteres que tiene cada uno.

A continuación un ejemplo con html.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<style>
    .card {
        padding: 5px;
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .card-body {
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .bloqueinfo:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card-group mb-2 bloqueinfo">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit adipisicing.
                            </h4>
                            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/230" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card-group mb-2 bloqueinfo">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">
                                Integer ut leo purus. Fusce leo augue, consectetur a massa id, mollis accumsan diam.
                            </h4>
                            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/230" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

¿Cómo podría mantener siempre el mismo alto de cada `div` según la longitud de caracteres que reciba como título? Para que siempre se mantenga la misma composición y no aparezca uno más alto que el otro.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aprovechar que **Bootstrap** hace que los `.col` de un `.row` que vayan en la misma línea midan lo mismo de alto. Entonces, como los `<div>` que quieres igualar son hijos directos de esos `.col`, puedes hacer que midan lo mismo de alto diciéndoles que tengan de altura el máximo que les permita su padre.

```
.card-group {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Bonus:**

Si haces que el cuerpo de la card sea `display: flex`, que tenga comportamiento de columna y que además el espacio no ocupado por elementos esté entre medias de los elementos, puedes conseguir que la imagen siempre esté posicionada abajo del todo del `<div>` independientemente de lo que ocupe el título de la card.

```
.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**Ejemplo ejecutable:**

```css
.card-group {
  height: 100%;
}

.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<style>
    .card {
        padding: 5px;
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .card-body {
        height: auto !important;
    }
    .bloqueinfo:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card-group mb-2 bloqueinfo">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit adipisicing.
                            </h4>
                            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/230" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card-group mb-2 bloqueinfo">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">
                                Integer ut leo purus. Fusce leo augue, consectetur a massa id, mollis accumsan diam. nteger ut leo purus. Fusce leo augue, consectetur a massa id, mollis accumsan diam.
                            </h4>
                            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/230" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu aportación, es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Espero no haberte robado mucho tiempo.
Que tengas un buen día! Marcaré tu respuesta como correcta.